# How to create a wordpress widget based on post settings

Tags: wordpress, widget, shortcode, boilerplate

I would like to create a WordPress plugin/widget that I can add to my post either through the Visual Composer area (widget should be selectable) or simply as a shortcode.

The functionality of this widget is that it should allow me to take the settings of that post as an argument in the main function so that I can change the output of the widget based on what is selected for the post.

For example, I have categories for all my posts and if I have a certain category selected, I want to change the output of the widget based on that.

Does anyone know of a good boilerplate to get me started with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own widget using the [Widget API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API) or the [Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API%20%22Codex%20-%20Shortcode%20API) for shortcodes.

Since you want to change the content shown in your, for instance, widget, based on the current post, in the `widget()` method (which is the method that prints your widget's content in the frontend) you can add your conditionals or whatever you want to print there.

The `$post` is available in your widget, so you can use functions like `get_post_meta()` to retrieve the post's settings if you use custom fields, or any other function like `get_the_ID()` or `has_category()`.

For example:

```
/**
 * Outputs the content of the widget
 *
 * @param array $args
 * @param array $instance
 */
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    if ( has_category( 'books' ) ) {
        echo 'Hey!, I have the Books category!';
    } else {
        echo "Hey... I don't.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. It helped me get to the answer I needed.
Within the shortcode function, I was able to use `get_post()` which returned me all my post data as well as `wp_get_object_terms( $id, 'portfolio_categories')` which helped me get the list of categories for my post.
Thanks!